# Main Div background color not appearing on sub Div

Tags: html, css

I have a concern. I have given three DIV. First is main and othr two are child. 
Out of two child, one child is for left side and one child is for right side. 
I have given main div background color as white but its not appearing on the background color of both the child.

Simple, I want the main div background color should appear on the child div as long as the main div close. Below is my codes

```
<div style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
Its showing here only white color

<div style="width:250px;  float:left; padding:10px;">
<p>hello its sam </p>
<p>hello its sam </p>
<p>hello its sam </p>
<p>hello its sam </p>
<p>hello its sam </p>
</div>

<div style="width:660px;   border-left: 1px solid #CCC; padding:10px; float:right;">
<p>Yes its sam</p>
<p>Yes its sam</p>
<p>Yes its sam</p>
<p>Yes its sam</p>
<p>Yes its sam</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Try adding `overflow:auto` to the CSS of the item with the background-color. Float sometimes doesn't work all the way you want it to.

Comment: You should clear the floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your floats.

Adding this line after the floats will solve the problem.

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

New HTML:

```
<div style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">Its showing here only white color
    <div style="width:250px;  float:left; padding:10px;">
        <p>hello its sam</p>
        <p>hello its sam</p>
        <p>hello its sam</p>
        <p>hello its sam</p>
        <p>hello its sam</p>
    </div>
    <div style="width:660px;   border-left: 1px solid #CCC; padding:10px; float:right;">
        <p>Yes its sam</p>
        <p>Yes its sam</p>
        <p>Yes its sam</p>
        <p>Yes its sam</p>
        <p>Yes its sam</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shc0b595/)

Learn more about floats and clearing them [**here**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

---

You can use overflow as well, tho I would just use `clear: both;`.

[Demo Using Overflow Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shc0b595/1/)

*Note: I have done inline styles to match your code*

Comment: No problem, any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can economise a div too, you have two possibilities :

1. add overflow:hidden to parent div (with background color)

Result html :

```
    <div style="background-color:#FFFFFF; overflow:hidden">
    Its showing here only white color
    <div style="width:250px;  float:left; padding:10px;">
        <p>hello its sam </p>
        <p>hello its sam </p>
        <p>hello its sam </p>
        <p>hello its sam </p>
        <p>hello its sam </p>
    </div>
    <div style="width:660px;   border-left: 1px solid #CCC; padding:10px; float:right;">
        <p>Yes its sam</p>
        <p>Yes its sam</p>
        <p>Yes its sam</p>
        <p>Yes its sam</p>
        <p>Yes its sam</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrg6sh4L/)

Or you can add a "clearfix" class - .cf -more short

```
     /**
     * For modern browsers
     * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
     *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
     *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
     *    that are clearfixed.
     * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
     *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
     */
    .cf:before,
    .cf:after {
        content: " "; /* 1 */
        display: table; /* 2 */
    }

    .cf:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    /**
     * For IE 6/7 only
     * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
     */
    .cf {
        *zoom: 1;
    }
```

Explained [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

And you add just cf class to main div.